# Saving filter state during page revisit on input text box

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

i need to save the filter applied on input box, so that when user revisits the page next time he can see that the filter already applied on input box? so can anyone help me to how can i save the filter value and restore it during revisit

Comment: How about cookies, or `localStorage`?

Comment: i tried using localstorage however it was able to give me value during revisit of page without filter applied on the value stored.